# Get results of Struts2 action on change

Tags: ajax, jsp, struts2

**regForm.action** returns **regForm.jsp**

and this **regForm.jsp** has following ajax script like this.

```
function checkDupAjax() {
  createAjax();
  var reg_id = document.getElementById("reg_id").value;
  xmlReq.open("GET", "checkDup.action?reg_id=" + reg_id, true);
  xmlReq.send(null);
}
```

and input

```
<input type="text" id="reg_id" name="reg_id" onkeyup="checkDupAjax()">
```

the **checkDupAjax** function sends **reg_id** to **checkDup.action** on "keyup".

**checkDup.action** checks the validation of **reg_id** and returns **String isDup**.

```
public String getIsDup() {
  return isDup; // will be either "true" or "false" depends on validation
}
```

Again, **checkDup.action** will be called and return the result **String isDup** everytime I type on "reg_id" input field.

This is what I got so far and works as I intenented, but stuck from here.

My goal is to display **String isDup** in **regForm.jsp** so user can check its validation on typing in input field.

struts.xml is like this so far.

```
<action name="regForm" class="common.RegFormAction">
  <result>/common/registration/registrationForm.jsp</result>
</action>

<action name="checkDup" class="common.CheckDuplicateAction">
  <result type="chain">regForm</result>
</action>
```

but I have no idea what to result from **checkDup.action**.
I checked **${isDup}** in **regForm.jsp** doesn't change on typing. Any advice please?

Comment: what is createAjax();

Comment: You're almost there, but still suffering some client-server confusion. Your ajax call needs an `onsuccess` listener than is a `function()` that takes the result of the ajax call and puts it into the DOM. I don't know what Javascript framework, if any, you are using but [this tutorial](http://danielnouri.org/notes/2011/03/13/an-ajax-page-update-mini-tutorial/) might be helpful.

Comment: Incidentally, making an ajax call for every change of the field is somewhat inefficient. Struts2 has a [validation framework](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/validation.html) and that framework supports [client side validation](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/client-side-validation.html) so you don't have to reinvent the wheel.